# Why is the Pip-Boy so inconsistent when invisible?

Tags: fallout-4

Sometimes I find it impossible to look at the Pip-Boy screen while invisible.

I understand this might be some sort-of intentional trade-off but the effect seems way too inconsistent, as shown below:

[image: icons appear clearly with no background]

[image: completely invisible Pip-Boy]

[image: icons appear clearly with background]

[image: saturated icons]

Comment: I've ran into these issues even while visible (although VERY rarely), so I doubt it is intentional. Especially your second image.... that's just odd and too non-intuitive for me to believe that was intended behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, the Pip-Boy only becomes entirely invisible if you just crouched or stopped moving right before using your Pip-Boy. It is likely a bug, where you're seeing the Pip-Boy's transitional state between being visible and invisible.

The only fix is to wait a little bit after crouching or stopping, until your character turns invisible, before you use your Pip-Boy. Naturally, standing up or unequipping the Chameleon equipment would be even better, but not necessarily what you want to do.